# How can Maven Shade Plugin relocate multiple versions of a transitive dependency?

Tags: java, maven, dependency-management, maven-shade-plugin, build-dependencies

I have two dependencies, *artifact-a* and *artifact-b*. Each depends on a different version of *artifact-c*. How can I shade artifacts  to use these different dependencies? (Or else to have *artifact-a* use a shaded dependency and *artifact-b* use the normal one.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>group-a</groupId>
            <artifactId>artifact-a</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
<!-- artifact-a uses version 3 of artifact-c.
How do I relocate version 3 without conflicting with version 4?
                <groupId>group-c</groupId>
                <artifactId>artifact-c</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
-->
      </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>group-b</groupId>
            <artifactId>artifact-b</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0</version>
<!-- artifact-b uses version 4 of artifact-c. 
How do I relocate version 4 without conflicting with version 3?
                <groupId>group-c</groupId>
                <artifactId>artifact-c</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.0</version>
-->
      </dependency>
```

Comment: could you try using `<artifactSet>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>group-c:artifact-c:*:4.0.0</include>
                                </includes>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>group-c:artifact-c:*:3.0.0</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </artifactSet>` within maven shade configuration.

Comment: I don't think this is possible.  Normally Maven will ignore one of the dependencies (it will say "omitted for version x.y.z" when you analyze the dependencies).  Using two different dependencies containing the same classes won't work unless you've seperated the dependencies completely using different class loaders.

Comment: @nullpointer thank you, but I can't exclude either of these versions of "c", since "a" and "b" require different  versions of "c".

Answer (score 1):

This can probably done by creating new Maven modules whose only purpose is to shade *artifact-a* and its dependencies (respectively *artifact-b*). Then, the main module would depend on these two new modules.